# Prove that $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c) \leq 2$ [ when $0 \leq a \leq 2$ , $0 \leq b \leq 2$ , $0 \leq c \leq 2$ ]

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, maxima-minima

Let $a$ , $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $0 \leq a \leq 2$ , $0 \leq b \leq 2$ , $0 \leq c \leq2$ .

Prove that $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c) \leq 2$

When does that equality hold?

Comment: you need to show your attempt or it will get closed.

Comment: Set partials to zero, and get factorable expressions to find various relations on a,b,c.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote $L:= (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

WOLG, there are only two cases: $a\le b \le c$ or $a\ge b \ge c$.

In the first case, the term $L$ is negative (then, it is smaller than $2$), so, we focus only on the second case where $a\ge b \ge c$. Applying the AM-GM inequality:
$$\begin{align}
L&= 2 (a-b)(b-c)\left(\frac{a-c}{2} \right)\\
\le &2\cdot \left(\frac{(a-b)+(b-c)+\left(\frac{a-c}{2} \right)}{3} \right)^3= \frac{(a-c)^3}{4} \le \frac{(2-0)^3}{4} = 2
\end{align}$$

The equality occurs if and only if $(a,b,c) = (2,1,0)$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number line , where we have $0,1,2$.
Somewhere in that interval , we have the variables $A,B,C$ in some order.

[image: ABC]

Let us reorder (rename) the variables such that we have the order $A,B,C$
We want to maximize $X(A,B,C)=|(A-B)(B-C)(C-A)|$

When $|(A-C)|$ ( which is the largest term here ) is kept constant , then it is easy to see that $X$ is locally maximized when $B$ is in the Exact Middle , that is $|(A-B)|=|(B-C)|$.

We can increase this local maxima by increasing $|(A-C)|$
Increasing $|(A-C)|$ will give us $|(A-C)|=2$ , where $A=0$ & $C=2$

The global maxima will then occur when $B$ is in the Exact Middle , that is $B=1$.
Hence , Maximum $X$ is $|(0-2)(2-1)(1-0)|=2$

All other $X$ values will be less than that maximum.
Equality occurs when-ever the variables are $(0,1,2)$ in some order.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.